# SFTP to a legacy server using UNIX

Tags: unix, sftp, ksh, expect

I have a requirement to connect to a different server using SFTP with username and password for sending files from Oracle Server to a legacy server.

How do I achieve this using a UNIX Shell script(KSH)? Please help!

Thanks,
Arun

Answer (score 1):

You can copy using scp:

```
scp mylocalfile.txt remoteuser@remotehost:/path/to/target/file.txt
```

Does that help you?

Comment: This is moving the file but I am not able to return back to the command promt. Also I am connecting using a password, the server is not pre-authenticated. I cannot give the password during the run time of this script.

Comment: @arun What kind of access do you have to the various machines? Given that you have access to both hosts you could set up passwordless logins using certificates. Works like a charm.

Comment: I cannot give you the access as I am working on a very controlled environment. Following are my limited knowledge on my other server (which is a client server for my current project) - user, host and password.
Also I am not allowed to use SSH keys between two servers for passwordless authentication. Can we do something with expect command in unix?

Comment: The [wikipedia page for expect has an sftp example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect#Examples).